# how to manage multiple data sources over multiple apps

Tags: java, database, tomcat, server, middleware

In our small company we have databases that is used by different software. For example a database that contains a user table with firstname, lastname, mailaddress, phonenumber.

This shall be shared over multiple software applications. What is best design to use this table in multiple software applications. They are windows applications, SPA webapps and an android app and ios 7 app.

What is the best way, so we don't have to hard code the connection string in each app?

Is there something like Dependency Injection or JNDI?

Comment: Yes .. create multiple datasource and during lookup or DI provide the name of datasource which you want to use.

Comment: but how do i exactly make a lookup that works on mac os, ubuntu and windows server?

Answer (score 0):

You can you use Spring JDBC in your applications, if you need Dependency injection. 
[Link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/)

Edit: 
Ok so you want a common datasource configuration that will be shared by all your applications in one server. There are so many work arounds for example, you can save the connection properties in a file  on your servers physical drive and have you applications read the common file. So in case your connection string changes you can just change the file.

Comment: And how do i inject the datasource into different apps? i don't want to write the same string to the dataserver, because if we expand or change our ips or hostnames.. i want someway that the server on which the application is running tells the application where the datasource can be found, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using a single database by different applications is not a best practice.

Create API and provide services as web services to different apps. OR you can use middle-ware to have connection with different platforms/applications

Comment: what is best practice on the API approach? write an api and make a lib of it in a maven repository and update it? where shall i store the URL to the API-Server? What middleware can you suggest, is there opensource middleware that features just the basic requirements?